# Given $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i f_i=0_E$ prove that $\alpha_1 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have $E$ a vector space of functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Let $a_1 > a_2 > ... > a_n$ be such that $n \geq 1$ . Let $f_1,..,f_n$ be vectors of E such that $\forall x \ \in \ \mathbb{R}, f_i(x)=\exp ^{a_ix}$. Let $\alpha_1,....,\alpha_n$ be such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i f_i=0_E$

Prove that $\alpha_1=0$

I tried factorising by $e^{a_1x}$ but still do not see how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: I performed a few grammatical edits to your question to clarify it somewhat. Hope it's OK.  Cheers!

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can in fact show $\alpha_i = 0$, $1 \le i \le n$:

"Factorizing by $e^{a_1x}$" is a good way to start; that, combined with some elementary knowledge about the exponential function, will drive the solution home.

We are given that

$\sum_1^n \alpha_i e^{a_i x} = 0; \tag{1}$

we write (1) as

$e^{a_1 x}(\alpha_1 + \sum_2^n  \alpha_i e^{(a_i - a_1)x})  = 0; \tag{2}$

note we have "factored out" $e^{a_1 x}$; since $e^{a_1x}$ is never $0$,  we may divide (2) by $e^{a_1x}$ and obtain

$\alpha_1 +  \sum_2^n \alpha_i e^{(a_i - a_1)x} = 0; \tag{3}$

observing that $a_i - a_1 < 0$ for $2 \le i \le n$, we let $x \to \infty$ in (3) and see that every factor $e^{(a_i - a_1)x}$ vanishes in the limit, leaving us with

$\alpha_1 = 0. \tag{4}$

By virtue of (4), (1) now becomes

$\sum_2^n \alpha_i e^{a_i x} = 0; \tag{5}$

we may now repeat the above process and show successively that $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3$, $\ldots$, $\alpha_n = 0$.

The upshot is of course that the functions $e^{a_i x}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$.